# Prove the continuous function is not necessarily absolutely continuous

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be continuous on $I=[0,1]$, and absolutly continuous on $[\epsilon,1]$ for any $0<\epsilon<1$.

(i) Show that $f$ may not be absolutely continuous on $I.$

(ii) Show that $f$ is absolutely continuous on $I$ if it is increasing.

(ii)Show that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is absolutly continuous BUT not Lipschitz on $I$.

I am struggling with the first part, I tried to find a finite disjoint collection of open intervals in $I$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^nl(I_i)<\delta$ for any $\delta>0$, but $$\sum_{i=1}^n|f(b_i)-f(a_i)|\geq \epsilon$$
where $I_i=(a_i,b_i).$ So I would appreciate any help with that.

Comment: Let $f(x) = x\sin(x) $ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$.  $f$ is continuous but not absolutely continuous on any interval that contains $0$.

Comment: Can you explain that more please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Let $f$ be the function given by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x\sin(\pi/2x)&,x\ne0\\\\
0&,x=0
\end{cases}$$

Take $\epsilon=1$.  Let $\delta >0$ be given.

Then, take $x_k =\frac1{Nk}$ and $y_k=\frac1{N(k+1)}$ for $N$ and odd integer and $1/\delta <N$.

Show that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^N|x_k-y_k|<\delta$, but $\sum_{k=1}^N|f(x_k)-f(y_k) |\ge1$.

Comment: @ahmed Please  let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: And please feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit of course. ;-)

Comment: I can not see where $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[\epsilon,1]$ with $1>\epsilon>0$

Comment: So is it true when $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then it is absolutely continuous?

Comment: If $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$.  Here, for all fixed $0<\epsilon <1$, $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[\epsilon,1]$.  Note that differentiability alone does not suffice as the function $g(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^4)$ for $x\ne0$ and $g(0)$ is differentiable on $[-1,1]$, is not continuously differentiable at $0$, and is not absolutely continuous on sets that contain $0$..

Comment: I like that, thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.  It was my pleasure.